# Can't get Intuit Customer Data Aggregation API to work using PHP SDK/App

Tags: php, intuit-partner-platform

I just can't seem to use the SDK/Sample-app that Intuit recommends, [found here](https://github.com/treehousetim/phpaggcat). 
I've attempted the simplest example.php included (and more), in many ways. No go.

Did anyone managed to get [Intuit CAD](https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata) PHP sdk working? If so, please share your experience.

Thanks!

Comment: Any errors? Do you have errors turned on?

Comment: The most errors I can get from the code (I use a debugger so I can very finely see what's going on) is: "400 Code:MissingRequiredField,Type:SYSTEM".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my local windows machine.  I had to change curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0) on both the api call and class.aggcatauth.php

Comment: well, thanks for the feedback but it came too late for Intuit - with the NOGO support and lousy API + documentation we went for their competitor - Yodlee (which I must note has not much better API, hardly adequate documentation, but way better support that helped us get through adoption stage).

Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @Carcione, I have swapped the variable how you described, but I am still also getting the error:

400 Code:MissingRequiredField,Type:SYSTEM

Comment: @BoazRymland I agree completely, but their pricing is way better

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is an issue with forming the signed_url using the oauthsimple.php 3rd party library.  The oauth_signature appears to be missing and therefore causing the 400 error (MissingRequiredField).

Replace line 292 in oauthsimple.php with the following would solve the problem:

```
'signed_url' => $this->_path . '?' . $this->_normalizedParameters(),
```

Answer (score 0):

An official fix has been pushed to the master branch by jrconlin.  Please use the latest OAuthSimple.php to address the previously seen 400 (MissingRequiredField) error.

https://github.com/jrconlin/oauthsimple/tree/master/php